# How to insert Image file using longblob datatype

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to query insert images, using a specific path, im using longblob as data type from my database
Im currently using this code, but when I will view the image from my database it is null:

```
 insert into table(pic) values ("C:\arrow.png") ;
```

And What If I will substitute it to a picturebox, mypicturebox1 highlight as error.

```
 cmd = new odbc.odbccommand("insert into table(pic) values ('" picturebox1.image'")",con)
```

Comment: The correct syntax can be found in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8230197/16959

Comment: maybe encode the image as base64 will do the trick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload image directly through mySQL Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439202/upload-image-directly-through-mysql-command-line)

Comment: no sir, i have an empty data on my table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Load\_File doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8229951/load-file-doesnt-work)

Comment: cmd = new odbc.odbccommand("insert into table(pic) values ('" & picturebox1.image & '")",con)

Comment: operator & is not deffines for types 'String'. still wrong