# How to insert images in blob in mysql table using only sql syntax (without PHP)?

Tags: mysql, database, blob, mysql-loadfile

1. Hi,I am new to SQL and I wanted to store images in the database.I already created a column with blob data type and tried to execute the following statement as given here

```
INSERT INTO `abc`
    (`img`)
    SELECT  
        BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(
            Bulk 'C:\Users\adity\Desktop\New folder\a.png', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

which gives error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
>                   Bulk `C:\Users\name\Desktop\New folder\a.png`, SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB' at line 4

I also tried following code as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8439229/2820063)

```
insert into table `abc`(`img`) values('C:\Users\name\Desktop\New folder\an.jpg') where id=1;
```

which gives the error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table `abc`(`img`) values('C:\Users\adity\Desktop\New folder\an.jpg') where id=1' at line 1

So please suggest me how to store images in a blob without using php,etc and simply using simple sql insert statement.I am using wamp server for my database.

2. I know that I should use file system for images instead of using database.But what does a file system actually mean.Does it mean a file or image hosting site whose address will be stored in database.

Comment: please don't tag sql-server when the question is only about mysql!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload image directly through mySQL Command Line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439202/upload-image-directly-through-mysql-command-line)

Comment: TYPO - There us no WHERE clause on a simple INSERT query

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that command is a MSSQL syntax. Try this command:

```
INSERT INTO `abc`
(`img`)
VALUES
(LOAD_FILE('C:/Users/adity/Desktop/New folder/a.png'))
```

This command stores image as a BLOB

Comment: The statement executed successfully and now table looks something like [this](http://s30.postimg.org/8uzx8rrg1/Capture2.jpg).Is it correct and what format is it?

Comment: Yes that's the correct format of the BLOB. Are you expecting an image will show up there? That's not how it works. You can use this BLOB to display the image. You can refer here how to display BLOB using PHP. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556773/php-display-image-blob-from-mysql

Answer (score 4):

Through Mysql workbench, its very easy to load images into database using the following steps.

1. Right click on the value of the (blob)column in the table and select "Load value from file".
2. Then we can provide the image path in the system.
3. Then it will converted into byte array and stored it automatically.
4. finally save the changes of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Below works for me,

However, I was able to get it done by moving the image(`fileName.jpg`) file first in to below folder(in my case) `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads` and then I executed below command and it works for me,

```
INSERT INTO `abc`
(`img`)
VALUES
(LOAD_FILE('C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/an.jpg'));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `WHERE id=1` ??

Comment: Im was answering the question. :D

Comment: An INSERT query does NOT have a `WHERE` clause