# How to upload an image from web server directory e.g. ( www/images/myImage.jpg) to mysql databse

Tags: php, mysql

I have an image which is initially from a link and I download it using php then save it to my image folder in a web server/site but I am having difficulties to save it to my database.

There is probably some article that talks about this but I failed to find it. I have been researching for hours now but got nothing.

Comment: i use php. it will do for me! i am trying to avoid using a form which  posts the image first and later capture it in php and upload to mysql.

Comment: you should make an attempt and show your working here. People don't take kindly to requests that have not made a genuine attempt. provide a [mcve] and ask for specific help of where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This question had been answered here: [How to insert images in blob in mysql table using only sql syntax (without PHP)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328601/how-to-insert-images-in-blob-in-mysql-table-using-only-sql-syntax-without-php#34328879)

Using PHP you could do this in reverse:

[Php : Convert a blob into an image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106470/php-convert-a-blob-into-an-image-file#6273415)

This means you will have to `fopen()` your file and `INSERT…` in mysql.